# Android webview perform double click when doing a single tap

Tags: android-webview

i'm have a problem with android webview on some device. When i do a single click, webview performs a double click and when i do a long tap, it performs as a single click.

Here is my webview setting code:

```
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(false);
    webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webSettings.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
    // Cleaning previous cookies
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(baseContext);
    CookieManager cookies = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookies.removeAllCookie();
    webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
    webView.setInitialScale(width*100/320);
    //webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    webView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.body_bg);
    webView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {// Android v3.0+
        webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
```

Do i make a wrong somewhere? Anyone can give a suggestion? I'm sorry because my bad English. Thank you for your help in advance.

Update: i found the reason of this problem. When i set webview scale is 1, it's seem ok but when i set scale large than 1, i have this bug. I also tested with default browser and the phenomenon is same. Can anyone help me?